# Pivot dataset with column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

if you have a table (example)

```
   declare @MyTable table (
CustomerName nvarchar(50),
BirthDate datetime,
BirtPlace nvarchar(50),
Phone nvarchar(50),
Email nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @MyTable
        (
         CustomerName,
         BirthDate,
         BirtPlace,
         Phone,
         Email
        )
values  (
         'Customer1', 
         '12.05.1990', 
         'Place1', 
         N'+000125456789', 
         N'customer@customer.com' 
        )
```

Is it possible to get following result set:

```
    CustomerName   Customer1
    BirtDate       1990-12-05 
    BirtPlace      Place1
    Phone          +000125456789
    Email          customer@customer.com
```

Something like pivot, but i don't have any idea how to get to this result.

Comment: I think what you actually want is `UNPIVOT`, not pivot.

Comment: you can refer this solution :  **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server**
and
**http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/497432**

Answer (score 3):

As you want to change columns to rows the function you want is `unpivot` not `pivot`.

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT col, val
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        CustomerName, 
        CAST(BirthDate AS NVARCHAR(50)) BirthDate, 
        BirtPlace, 
        Phone, 
        Email  
    FROM @MyTable
) AS t
UNPIVOT 
(
    val FOR col IN (CustomerName, BirthDate, BirtPlace, Phone, Email)
) AS u
```

Comment: Thanks this helps me

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT myColumn, myDetail    
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CustomerName,
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),BirthDate,121) AS BirthDate,
        BirtPlace,
        Phone,
        Email
    FROM
        @MyTable
) AS A
UNPIVOT
(
    myDetail FOR myColumn IN (CustomerName, BirthDate, BirtPlace, Phone, Email)
) AS tbUnpivot
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `unpivot` issue, and if you used old version sql server 2000, this `unpivot` syntax will not work, then you can use `UNION`:

```
SELECT 'CustomerName' AS colName, CustomerName AS colVal FROM @MyTable
UNION
SELECT 'BirthDate' AS colName, CAST(BirthDate AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS colVal FROM @MyTable
UNION
SELECT 'BirthPlace' AS colName, BirthPlace AS colVal FROM @MyTable
UNION
SELECT 'Phone' AS colName, Phone AS colVal FROM @MyTable
UNION
SELECT 'Email' AS colName, Email AS colVal FROM @MyTable;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT CustomerName,BirtDate,BirtPlace,Phone,Email FROM @MyTable\G
```

You have no ID and no Foreign keys so i think thats a way to solve your problem. The \G give´s you the SQL-query as a list.

```
  values  (
     'Customer1', '1990-12-05', 'Place1', '+000125456789', 'customer@customer.com' 
    );
```

I hope i could help you

Have a nice Day

Comment: The `\G` is a rather strange syntax and not appropriate with SQL Server. You might read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2277014/5089204