# SQL injection attack in LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a file that runs a SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE "%<String Passed to It>%"`

I am trying to test for basic web security here. How can I break this query to drop the `items` table, without using `spaces` or `semi-colons`

Comment: If the `<String Passed to It>` is passed to it in a `[n]varchar` parameter, then you don't have to do anything. If it is concatenated into the query, then please don't do that.

Comment: In theory, you can't break the query without being able to inject a semicolon to terminate the select first.  But, how can you enforce no semicolons, given that the input text very well could have a literal semicolon as part of that text?  Your safest bet here is to use a prepared statement, and let MySQL worry about sanitizing your query.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the value of the  to be:

'\gDROP TABLE items\g--

You will need to escape that apostrophe.

Making you're query look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%'\gDROP TABLE items\g--%'
```

In mySQL \g is equivalent to a semi-colon.  However, I'm not sure if spacing is required as I do not currently have a local installation of mySQL set up, and I do not know exactly what language and framework you're using to execute that query.

However, the other comments are right that using a prepared statement and parameters rather than building the SQL string in code is the way to go in trying to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277014/why-the-g-in-select-from-table-name-g/40030346)

Comment: hmm.. That didn't seem to work. What kind of SQL injection attacks can be made to ignore the LIKE clause?

Comment: I would suggest a review of some common SQL Injection tactics and reasons.  In the case of a like or an equals, SQL injection can be used to not only damage your database schema, but also to map it or extract out key information from the database. In this [link] (http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) you can find not only the reasons but ways to mitigate the risk of an attack explained really well.  That link does explain what kind of attacks will attempt to ignore the like clause, and how to precent it.  Pay close attention to the bound parameters section.